# Updating a view with CHECK OPTION succeeds unexpectedly

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

How does the `CHECK OPTION` work on a view? When trying to update the view, it succeeds.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Test](
    [Country] [nvarchar](20) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

INSERT [Test] VALUES ('England'), ('USA'), ('Australia');

CREATE VIEW dbo.TestView AS   
SELECT Country FROM  dbo.Test 
WHERE Country = N'USA'
WITH CHECK OPTION;
```

I attempt to insert a new row via the view, and it **fails as expected**, due to the `WITH CHECK OPTION` with the expected error message `The attempted insert or update failed because the target view either specifies WITH CHECK OPTION`

```
INSERT INTO dbo.TestView (Country) VALUES (N'Canada');
```

This update, however, succeeds unexpectedly:

```
UPDATE dbo.TestView  SET Country = N'ddsffd';
```

No rows are returned then when executing `SELECT * FROM dbo.TestView`.

What's going on here?

Comment: The UPDATE statement should in fact fail. What version of SQL are you using?

Answer (score 3):

`UPDATE` statement will throw an exception only if the underlying table already contains the data that satisfies `WHERE` condition in the `VIEW`. Otherwise `UPDATE` statement does not violate the `CHECK` condition, because there are no data for modification in the `VIEW`.

Check:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Test](
    [Country] [nvarchar](20) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY];


CREATE VIEW dbo.TestView AS 
SELECT Country FROM
dbo.Test WHERE Country = N'USA'
WITH CHECK OPTION;
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.[Test] (Country) VALUES (N'USA');

UPDATE dbo.TestView 
SET Country = N'ddsffd';
```

Answer (score 0):

Your case works for me in MSSQL2008 (both the INSERT and the UPDATE are rejected).

Note that if the base table of the view has an INSTEAD OF trigger for INSERT and/or UPDATE, any corresponding actions on the view *will silently ignore* the WITH CHECK OPTION (on the basis that the trigger may transform the supplied values, so the view cannot know whether the actual inserted/updated rows would violate the view's filter or not).

If you have such a case, you're forced to write INSTEAD OF triggers for both INSERT and UPDATE on the view and check the filter yourself. That does mean that INSERTs on the view will not take DEFAULT clauses from the base table into account, so you'll have to apply ISNULL to values from INSERTED to be able to insert them into the base table properly).